# gmaps.js - How to filter markers using select?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-fusion-tables, gmaps.js

I'm able to filter markers without gmaps.js, using Google Maps JS. However, the code below does not work in conjunction with gmaps.js. Error declares: *changeMap is not a function*. My amateurish JS level can't figure it out. Any ideas?

My current incorrect JS with gmaps.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var layer;
var tableid = 2796050;
var map = new GMaps({
el: '#map_canvas',
lat: 33.68906,
lng: -78.886694,
zoom: 11
});
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
map.loadFromFusionTables({
query: {
select: '\'Location\'',
from: '1LNKdPBYZOlszyjQqzUhoqsQXVdkyQ7pP2o2ft9o'
},
suppressInfoWindows: false,
events: {
click: function(point){
infoWindow.setPosition(point.latLng);
}
}
});
// problem area
function changeMap() {
var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
if(!searchString) {
layer.setQuery("SELECT 'Latitude' FROM " + tableid);
return;
}
layer.setQuery("SELECT 'Latitude' FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'Category' = '" + searchString + "'");
}
});
```

HTML

```
<!-- HTML -->
<form>
<label>Category </label>
<select id="search-string" onchange="changeMap(this.value);">
<option value="">All Places</option>
<option value="Attractions">Attractions</option>
<option value="Dining">Dining</option>
<option value="Shopping">Shopping</option>
<option value="Services">Services</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this one to work, you need to add the `<script>` block before the bit of HTML.

Since you are using jQuery anyway, consider writing an event instead of `changeMap` function. Firstly, remove the `onchange` attribute from `select`. And change this:

```
function changeMap() {
    var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
    if(!searchString) {
        layer.setQuery("SELECT 'Latitude' FROM " + tableid);
        return;
    }
    layer.setQuery("SELECT 'Latitude' FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'Category' = '" + searchString + "'");
}
```

... to this:

```
$('#search-string').change( function() {
    var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
    if(!searchString) {
        layer.setQuery("SELECT 'Latitude' FROM " + tableid);
        return;
    }
    layer.setQuery("SELECT 'Latitude' FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'Category' = '" + searchString + "'");
})
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Thanks for your help, Salman, but after adding your suggestions, the select still doesn't filter out the markers. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/djmtype/Bbzdh/5/ I think the function needs to be implemented in the same fashion as the tooltip. Any ideas? Sorry, JS is not my first language, nor 2nd or 3rd.

Comment: I think some part of your code might be missing. Where do you initialize `layer`?